# Unexpected error occured when processing Azure Analysis Services Tabular model

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have next error after processing my tabular model :

```
The DDL JSON request failed with the following error: Failed to execute XMLA. 
Error returned: 'An unexpected error has occurred.

The exception was triggered by the IDbCommand interface.
The exception was triggered by the IDbCommand interface.
The exception was triggered by the IDbCommand interface.
The exception was triggered by the IDbCommand interface.
The exception was triggered by the IDbCommand interface.
The exception was triggered by the IDataReader interface.
The exception was triggered by the IDbCommand interface.'..

Technical Details:
RootActivityId: 2404cde3-86fb-471a-b517-5a90470897c6
Date (UTC): 3/4/2019 10:59:16 AM
  0: PFError::SetLastError() line 2160 + 0x0 <br/>(sql\picasso\engine\src\pf\eh\pferror.cpp)
  1: PFSetLastError() line 2918 + 0x0 (sql\picasso\engine\src\pf\eh\pferror.cpp)
  2: PFSetLastErrorExTag() line 3474 + 0x27 <br/>(sql\picasso\engine\src\pf\eh\pferror.cpp)
  3: 0x00007FFE500F9551 (symbolic name unavailable)
```

This error occurs in different places of model processing: sometimes in the beginning, sometimes after processing of a part of the model.

When I recreate model from the previous one script, it is processed without error, but in several days the same issue returns.

IDbCommand interface seems to indicate that is the issue is related to SQL database connection on which the model is built. But I can't understand the random nature of it.

I could find the similar issue occured in PowerBI when refreshing a connection to SQL data, but it doesn't help to resolve my case : 
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Report-Server/Error-when-Refreshing-SQL-Data/td-p/317866